# How do I resolve Postgresql error, "PL/Perl function must return reference to hash or array"?

Tags: postgresql

The follow code used to work in Postgresql 8.4.11 with perl v5.10.1:

```
=# select * From testfunction();
      testfunction      
------------------------
 http://www.google.com/
```

However, after doing a dump and load into Postgresql 9.1.3 with perl v5.14.2 I get:

```
ERROR:  PL/Perl function must return reference to hash or array
CONTEXT:  PL/Perl function "testfunction"
```

For reference, here is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testfunction(OUT text) AS $$
  use URI;
  return URI->new('http://www.google.com/')->canonical;
$$ LANGUAGE plperlu;
```

Again, the version of perl changed from `v5.10.1` to `v5.14.2`; however, the return from `Data::Peek` is the same across both versions:

```
$ perl -MData::Peek -MURI -e'DPeek(
    URI->new(q[http://www.google.com])->canonical
);'
```

Output on both versions of perl:

```
\PVMG("http://www.google.com/"\0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, coerce what you return to a string, should work fine in 8.4 and 9.1:

```
return URI->new('http://www.google.com/')->canonical().'';
```

See http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-bugs/2012-05/msg00096.php for my full response.

Comment: I think even better for this applciation would be `->canonical->as_string()`

Comment: Welcome to dba.se Alex and thanks for contributing here too :-)